# How to get the individual decode value in Sybase SQL?

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

I'm working in a Sybase database.I want to do the same thing as does the 'DECODE' function in Oracle.To achieve that I'm using 'CASE' function in my current project.'DECODE' is not working in Sybase database.

### Country is varchar by Data Type.

**When I'm running  "select Country from database ", then getting all the Country code accordingly below.I want to replace country code alias as Country Name.How can I achieve this**

**Note** - I can't modify the database.

```
CASE  WHEN Country='23077' THEN 'INDIA'
      WHEN Country='23078' THEN 'AUSTRALIA'
      WHEN Country='23079' THEN 'USA'
      WHEN Country='23080' THEN 'FRANCE'
      WHEN Country='23082' THEN 'SPAIN'
      WHEN Country='23083' THEN 'UK'
      WHEN Country='23084' THEN 'GERMANY'
      WHEN Country='23085' THEN 'CHINA'
      ELSE 'DOES NOT EXIST'
END AS Country,
```

**Note :-** The query is running without any error but only the Table's rows displays, not the data.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the best way to achieve this is to create a TABLE with country_code | country_name and and use a JOIN - databases are really good at stuff like that.

Comment: @Alex, I can't modify the database. I have only option select.

Comment: Using CASE is the right way to go. DECODE is basically shorthand for the CASE expression.